# How to make a difference between two function close to zero through iteration?

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, montecarlo

I need to construct a loop (simulation) that will iterate a certain number of times and display a value of warrant once the new firm value is close to the guess firm value. Specifically, the idea is to start out with a guess for the firm value (for example the stock price multiplied by the number of shares). Then you value the warrant as a call option (the code below) on this value multiplied by dilution factor, using the same volatility as the vol of the share price. You recompute then the value of the firm (number of shares times share price plus number of warrants times warrant price). This value will be different from the value of the firm you started with. Then you redo the procedure and after a few iterations you will see that the difference in values of the firm tends to zero. For this, I have a following code, but what I get is the following:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Please, help me to figure out the error given the code below:

```
 def bsm_call_value(S0, K, T, r, sigma):
    from math import log, sqrt, exp
    from scipy import stats
    S0 = float(S0)
    d1 = (log(S0 / K) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * sqrt(T))
    d2 = (log(S0 / K) + (r - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * sqrt(T))
    value = (S0 * stats.norm.cdf(d1, 0.0, 1.0) - K * exp(-r * T) *stats.norm.cdf(d2, 0.0, 1.0))
    return value

def warrant_1unobservable(S0, K, T, r, sigma, k, N, M, Iteration):
    for i in range(1, Iteration):  
    Guess_FirmValue = S0*N
    dilution = N/(N +k*M)
    warrant[i] = bsm_call_value(Guess_FirmValue[i]/N,100,1,0.1,0.2)*dilution
    New_FirmValue[i] = Guess_FirmValue[i]+ warrant[i]
    Guess_FirmValue[i] - New_FirmValue[i] == 0
return warrant                   

print(warrant_1unobservable(100,100,1,0.1,0.2,1,100,10, 1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a python expert and I'm not familiar with the algorithm you're using, but I'll point out a few things that could be causing the issue.

1) In `warrant_1observable`, you first assign `Guess_FirmValue` a scalar value (since both `S0` and `N` are scalars the way you call the function), and then you try to access it with an index as `Guess_FirmValue[i]`. My guess would be that this is causing the error you displayed, since you're trying to index/subscript a variable that, based on your function input values, would be an integer.

2) Both `warrant[i]` and `New_FirmValue[i]` are attempts to assign values to an indexed position in a list, but nowhere do you initialize these variables as lists. Lists in python are initialized as `warrant = []`. Also, it's likely that you would have to either a) pre-allocate the lists to the correct size based on the `Iteration` or b) use `append` to push new values onto the back of the list.

3) `Guess_FirmValue[i] - New_FirmValue[i] == 0` is a vacuous line of code. All this does is evaluate to either true or false, while performing no other operation. I imagine you're trying to check if the values are equal and then return, but that won't happen even if you stick this in an `if` statement. It is extremely unlikely that the floating-point representation of the values will ever be identical. This kind of break is accomplished by checking if the difference of the values is below some tolerance, which is set to be a very small number. Ex.:

```
if (abs(Guess_FirmValue[i] - New_FirmValue[i]) <= 1e-9):
    return ...
```